# Need help using nftables to drop SNMP packets containing a specific community string

Tags: snmp, nftables

I am trying to use nftables [v1.0.2 (Lester Gooch)] to drop SNMP packets containing the community string 'pawan'. I am trying to use the nftables payload expressions - raw payload expression to match SNMP packets containing community string public like this:

- nft add table ip filter
- nft 'add chain ip filter input { type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept; }'
- nft add rule ip filter input udp dport 161 @th,48,40 0x7077616e drop

Here @th (transport header) needs the offset and length in bits (https://www.mankier.com/8/nft#Payload_Expressions-Raw_Payload_Expression)

The SNMP community string “pawan” in the packet is represented by the hexadecimal string 0x707177616e.

To find the offset of this hexadecimal string 0x707177616e from the start of the UDP payload, need to know where the UDP payload starts. In a typical IP packet:

The Ethernet header is 14 bytes. The IP header is usually 20 bytes but can be longer if options are used. The UDP header is 8 bytes. So, the UDP payload typically starts at byte 42 (14 + 20 + 8) of the packet.

The SNMP community string “pawan” starts at byte 48 of the packet ("\x70\x61\x77\x61\x6e"), so its offset from the start of the UDP payload is 48 - 42 = 6 bytes. Offset in bits is 6 * 8 = 48 bits

The length of the string “pawan” is 5 bytes, so the length in bits is 5 * 8 = 40 bits.

So I am using an offset of 48 and a length of 40 to match this community string in the UDP payload.

However, this rule does not get applied as expected. Internally this is what the nftables takes it as:

nft list ruleset
table ip filter { chain input { type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept; udp dport 161 udp checksum 112 @th,64,24 0x77616e drop } }

Note that I configure it for @th,48,40,  but the kernel seems to misunderstand it as udp checksum 112 @th,64,24. So this nft rule is not working.

I need help to understand if I am supposed to do anything differently. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`@th` is not the start of the UDP payload – that's `@ih`, whereas `@th` is actually the start of the **t**ransport **h**eader (UDP header in this case).

With a 8-byte UDP header, the UDP payload starts at `@th,64`, so your SNMP community string field is at `@th,112` (if your nftables version is too old for `@ih`). Meanwhile, your 6 byte offset is still within the UDP header – and is indeed the checksum field.

Comment: Indeed 48 would be the checksum field as you pointed out. Thanks a lot for the explanation about @th.

Below is the Hex dump of my UDP payload. I noticed that based on that, my community string starts after the 7th byte (56 bits) in the UDP payload. So I am thinking the community string will be 64+56=120 (instead of 112). Is my understanding correct?

0000  30 28 02 01 01 04 05 70  61 77 61 6e a1 1c 02 04   0(·····p awan····
0010  46 04 0e 48 02 01 00 02  01 00 30 0e 30 0c 06 08   F··H···· ··0·0···
0020  2b 06 01 02 01 01 04 00  05 00                     +······· ··

Comment: I tried both offsets 112 and 120 but neither worked. I don't understand why though, struggling to get it right.